# How can I implement the contains and uniqueElements methods for this IntegerSet class? (homework)

Tags: java

For this assignment I am not permitted to use any of the built-in libraries. Only what was given to me and any other additional methods that I write.

The objective is to create a new class called `IntegerSet`. Here are the characteristics of `IntegerSet`.

1. Integers stored must be unique. (No duplicates).
2. The integer sets are ordered.

Within the `IntegerSet` class, all methods you see were given by the professor and simply need to be finished, except `binarySearch`, which I added for use in completing the `contains()` method, and the Quick Sort methods which I added to sort the array in the `uniqueElements` method.

I'm confused about how to complete the `contains()` and `uniqueElements()` methods. `uniqueElements()` should take an array and create a new array with the unique elements from the original. For example, `[1, 3, 1, 2, 1]` will return a new array containing `[1, 2, 3]`. My plan was to:

1. write a Quick Sort method to sort the array
2. create an array of size equal to the number of unique elements, and then copy the unique elements to this array.

I planned to do this second part by using the `contains()` method I created earlier. However, I now realize I can't. `tempArray.contains(value)`, and so I'm not sure what to do next.

My questions here are: Have I completed the contains method correctly? If so, how do I go about completing the UniqueElements method?

Please forgive me if this is a silly question. This is only the second class I've taken that involves any coding.

Here is my code for this assignment:

```
public class IntegerSet {

    // The array that represents the set.
    private final int set[];

    /**
     * The constructor for IntegerSet. When an IntegerSet is created it must be
     * initialized with an integer array. The set will then pull out the duplicated
     * items and keep the unique integers.
     * 
     * @param arr
     *            The array to create the set from.
     */
    public IntegerSet(int arr[]) {
        if (arr == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must not be null");
        }
        set = uniqueElements(arr);
    }

    /**
     * This is the size of the set which, in this case, is just the length of the
     * array.
     * 
     * @return The length of the set.
     */
    public int magnitude() {
        return set.length;
    }

    /**
     * This method is private and is used to help set up the set array. An integer
     * set is one in which the elements are unique (no duplicates) and are sorted.
     * 
     * @param arr
     *            The array that will be used to retrieve the unique elements from.
     * @return The new integer array that contains the unique elements from arr.
     */
    private int[] uniqueElements(int arr[]) {
        int tempArr[] = new int[arr.length - 1];
        int count = 0;
        sort(arr);
        
    }

    /**
     * This method returns whether or not value is located in the set. If the value
     * is in the set then return true otherwise return false. <br />
     * Example:
     * <pre>
     *      IntegerSet iS1 = new IntegerSet([1,2,3,4]); 
     *      iS1.contains(3); //returns true
     *      iS2.contains(6); //returns false
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The integer to look for.
     * @return True if value is located in the set otherwise false.
     */
    public boolean contains(int value) {
        if(binarySearch(set, 0, set.length - 1, value) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * A union of two sets is a new set that contains all elements from both sets.
     * This method takes another set and unions it with the set that calls this
     * method. A new IntegerSet is returned that contains the union of both sets.<br />
     * Example:
     * <pre>
     *      IntegerSet is1 = new IntegerSet([1, 2, 3, 4]); 
     *      IntegerSet is2 = new IntegerSet([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
     *      is1.union(is2) //returns new IntegerSet([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param otherSet
     *            The set to be unioned with.
     * @return A new IntegerSet that is the union of the calling set with the
     *         otherSet.
     */
    public IntegerSet union(IntegerSet otherSet) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * The intersection of two sets is a new set that contains elements that occur
     * in both sets. This method takes another set and intersects it with the set
     * that calls this method. A new IntegerSet is returned that contains the
     * intersection of the two sets. <br />
     * Example:
     * <pre>
     *      IntegerSet is1 = new IntegerSet([1,2,3,4]);
     *      IntegerSet is2 = new IntegerSet([3,4,5]);
     *      is1.intersection(is2) //returns new IntegerSet([3, 4]);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param otherSet
     *            The set to be intersected with.
     * @return A new IntegerSet that is the intersection of the calling set with the
     *         otherSet.
     */
    public IntegerSet intersection(IntegerSet otherSet) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of an IntegerSet type. The returned string
     * will have the following structure.
     * 
     * set{ elements in the set separated by a comma }.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("set{ ");
        for (int i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            sb.append(set[i]);
            if (i < set.length - 1) {
            sb.append(", ");
            }
        }
        sb.append(" }");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    //ADDED BY ME*******************************************
    //recursive method for binary search
    public static int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high, int key){  
        //if array is in order then perform binary search on the array
        if (high>=low){  
            //calculate mid
            int mid = low + (high - low)/2;  
            //if key =intArray[mid] return mid
            if (arr[mid] == key){  
            return mid;  
            }  
            //if intArray[mid] > key then key is in left half of array
            if (arr[mid] > key){  
            return binarySearch(arr, low, mid-1, key);//recursively search for key  
            }
            else       //key is in right half of the array
            {  
            return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, high, key);//recursively search for key 
            }  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }
    
 //BEGIN QUICK SORT 
    public static void sort(int arr[]) {
        quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length -1);
    }
    
    private static void quickSort(int arr[], int first, int last) {
        final int MIN_SIZE = 10;
        if(last - first + 1 < MIN_SIZE) {
            insertionSort(arr, first, last);
        }
        else {
            int pivotIndex = partition(arr, first, last);
            quickSort(arr, first, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, last);
        }
    }
    
    private static int partition(int arr[], int first, int last) {
        int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
        sortFirstMiddleLast(arr, first, mid, last);
        swap(arr, mid, last - 1); // move pivot
        int pivotIndex = last - 1; 
        int pivot = arr[pivotIndex];
        
        int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
        int indexFromRight = last - 2;
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            while(((Comparable) arr[indexFromLeft]).compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                indexFromLeft++;
            }
            while(((Comparable) arr[indexFromRight]).compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                indexFromRight--;
            }
            if(indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
                swap(arr, indexFromLeft, indexFromRight);
                indexFromLeft++;
                indexFromRight--;
            }
            else
                done = true;
        } // End while
        swap(arr, pivotIndex, indexFromLeft); // Place pivot
        pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;
        return pivotIndex;
    }
    
    private static void sortFirstMiddleLast(int arr[], int first, int mid, int last) {
    if(((Comparable) arr[first]).compareTo(arr[mid]) > 0) {
        swap(arr, first, mid);
    }
    if(((Comparable) arr[mid]).compareTo(arr[last]) > 0) {
        swap(arr, mid, last);
    }
    if(((Comparable) arr[first]).compareTo(arr[mid]) > 0) {
        swap(arr, first, mid);
    }
        
}
    
    private static void swap(int arr[], int idx1, int idx2) {
    int temp = arr[idx1];
    arr[idx1] = arr[idx2];
    arr[idx2] = temp;
}
    
    private static void insertionSort(int arr[], int first, int last) {
    for(int i = first; i < last; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j > first; j--) {
            int res = ((Comparable) arr[j]).compareTo(arr[j-1]);
            if(res < 0) {
                swap(arr, j, j-1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
    
    
}
```

Comment: Right off the bat, your method `uniqueElements` doesn't return anything and it is expected to return an array. So, edit your code that it compiles.

Comment: I used your code and completed `uniqueElements` based on what I suggested and works like a charm. That means your sort algorithm works. I didn't code `contains`, but you could code it based on what I suggested. If the source array is already sorted, you really don't need to call `contains()` method because you only need to look at the last insertion. If the source array is not sorted, then you need to call it and use binary search to see if the value to be inserted goes before or after the correct value. And, you will need to sort the target array after insertion.

Comment: I just took a look at your `contains()` method. You have a problem. Your `set` is final. That means it is constant. You would have to either make it not final, or your `contains` method must take an `int[]` as an argument.

Comment: hfontanez, it looks like `set` being final and the fact that `contains` takes an int rather than an int[] as an argument are both requirements that my professor made. However, I shouldn't actually need to use `contains` in the `uniqueElements` method based on the info you provided. I'll just need to find a way to make `contains` return true/false depending on if the value was located in the set. Will I still be able to do this?

Comment: In that case, sort the original (source) array and follow the firs set of instructions in my answer. That way you know that the current value in the output is always smaller than the new value to be inserted. By the way, if I answered your question fully, I will appreciate if you mark my answer as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't provide the solution, but I will do my best to describe the steps you must follow to complete your assignment.

Given an input array `[1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]` (length: 10, dup count: 7), the first step will be to sort the array. I will assume that your quicksort function works correctly. So, after sorting the array, you end up with `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`. This must be done before creating the new array containing the unique set. Why? It will be best to calculate the duplicate count to use the unique count to set the size of the new array (original length - duplicate count).

To calculate the duplicate count, you can start at index 0 (use variable `i`) and check if the value of the current index is equals to the value of the next index (`arr[i] == arr[i + 1]`). If so, you will increment `dupCount`. This process shall be repeated until `i` is equals to the length of the original array minus 2. Using the array above, this will be 8. This is because when at `arr[8]`, the next index is `arr[9]` or the last index location. Therefore, one more iteration and you will encounter an Array Index Out of Bounds exception.

Recapping, you will iterate through your original (sorted) array to count for duplicates.

```
int[] inputArr = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3};
int dupCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) dupCount++;
}
int[] outArr = new int[arr.length - dupCount];
```

In this case, there are 7 duplicate values. Since the original array size is 10, the new (output) array should be of length 3. And, that matches the predicted size for output array `[1, 2, 3]`.

```
current
  |
  v 
 [1][1][1][1][2][2][2][2][3][3]

 [0][0][0]
  ^
  |
current
```

When the new array is created, it will be filled with zeros since numeric primitives in Java are initialized to zero. Therefore, when the output array is created, it will be like this `[0, 0, 0]`. Now the task is to fill in the array with the unique values. You need to check that the target (output) array does not contain the value from the original (input) array. The very first insertion can be done blindly. So, you can simply do `outArr[0] = inputArr[0];`. After that, you need to check the value at each index. The easiest (in my opinion) is to start both at index 1 and only insert if the current value in the output array is not equal to the current value in the input array. Why? Since the original array is sorted, equal values means that the current value in the input array was already inserted (duplicate), a higher value cannot occur (this should be an exception case). A lower value means that the current input value must be inserted in the output array. In this case,

```
   current
     |
     v 
 [1][1][1][1][2][2][2][2][3][3]

 [1][0][0]
  ^
  |
current
```

Is the value at the current index in original array in the new array? Since the original array is sorted, the output array will be naturally sorted. So this addresses one of the requirements. It also makes insertion easily. Why? You only need to examine at the value at the current index in the output array. In the first iteration, the current value at index 0, is not equal than the value at the current index of the output array. This means that the current value at the original array must be inserted in the new array. The pointer of the original array must be incremented.:

```
      current
        |
        v 
 [1][1][1][1][2][2][2][2][3][3]

 [1][0][0]
  ^
  |
current
```

The second iteration shows the case where the new array contains the current value in the original array. Repeat the first step and increment the original array index.

```
            current
              |
              v 
 [1][1][1][1][2][2][2][2][3][3]

 [1][0][0]
  ^
  |
current
```

The previous steps repeated but now the values are different. This means the output array does not contain the value in the input array. Therefore, the index of the output array must be incremented first and then the new value must be inserted.

```
            current
              |
              v 
 [1][1][1][1][2][2][2][2][3][3]

 [1][2][0]
     ^
     |
   current
```

After insertion, the previous steps are repeated: The index of the new array is incremented and the values of the input and output arrays are compared. If the output array contains the value in the input array, the input array index is incremented. This will continue until a value not contained in the output array is found.

```
                        current
                          |
                          v 
 [1][1][1][1][2][2][2][2][3][3]

 [1][2][0]
     ^
     |
   current
```

Now that a new value is found, the insertion step must take place: increment the index of the new array, and insert the new value.

```
                        current
                          |
                          v 
 [1][1][1][1][2][2][2][2][3][3]

 [1][2][3]
        ^
        |
      current
```

At this point, since the output array is filled, it should be safe to stop the process. However, if you want to be extra safe, you could continue to iterate though the input array to see if the current value is in the output array. Since the index in the output array is not incremented until a new value is encountered, the process should complete without errors. HOWEVER, if a new value is encountered and the process attempts to insert a new value into the output array, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown and this is an indication that most likely the process to calculate the size of the new array is wrong, or something is wrong in the insertion part of the process.

If everything is OK, the process is complete. You have created a valid instance of `IntegerSet` where the values in the internal array of the class contains only unique values and these values are sorted.

**UPDATE**: Starting with an unsorted source array.
You can still start by blindly copying the values at index 0.

```
outArr[0] = inputArr[0];
```

Then, you will increment the pointer of the input (source) array and compare values.

```
   current
     |
     v 
 [1][3][2][2][1][1][2][1][2][3]

 [1][0][0]
  ^
  |
current
```

At this point, since the source array is not sorted, if the values are different, you must increment the index of the output array and do an insertion sort. This will determine whether the inserted value goes to the right or left of the current value in the output array. In this case, since 3 is greater than one, it will go to the right of the current value.

```
      current
        |
        v 
 [1][3][2][2][1][1][2][1][2][3]

 [1][3][0]
     ^
     |
   current
```

The process repeats. Since the new value is less than the current value, it will be inserted to the left. That means, the insertion sort will swap the values.

```
         current
           |
           v 
 [1][3][2][2][1][1][2][1][2][3]

 [1][2][3]
        ^
        |
      current
```

At this point, the creation of the unique set is done. But, as I stated before, you could continue to process the source array to see if there are values that were left off. If they were, the code will attempt to insert the new unique value at which point it will throw an exception. Again, this is a sign that calculating the size of the output array was done incorrectly or the insertion is bad.

Comment: I was just able to implement what you showed here and it's working! Thank you for taking the time to explain it so clearly.

Comment: @XanJo just in case, the contains method appears to be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Your method to implement uniqueElements is correct and this page explained how to do it
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-sorted-array/
but I used a third array to store the unique elements

```
private int[] uniqueElements(int arr[]) {     
     int tempArr[] = new int[arr.length-1];
     int h = 0;
     sort(arr);
     for(int i =0; i< arr.length-1; i++) {
         if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1])
             tempArr[h++] = arr[i];
     }
     tempArr[h++] = arr[arr.length-1];
     int [] resultArr = new int[h];
     for (int i = 0; i < h; i++){
         // copy unique array to new array with exactly the count of unique elements
         resultArr[i] = tempArr[i];
     }
     return resultArr;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

***you can use the hashmap's key***

```
//import classes and packages  
    import java.util.HashMap;   
      
    //create UniqueElementsExample1 class to get distinct element from the array  
    class UniqueElementsExample1 {   
        //main() method starts  
        public static void main(String args[])   
        {   
            //create an integer array having some duplicate elements   
            int arrayWithDuplicates[] = { 10, 3, 5, 3, 9, 22, 4, 3, 1, 5, 6 };  
      
            //create a hashmap having integer type of key-value  
            HashMap<Integer,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();   
              
            //use for loop to pull the elements of array to hashmap's key  
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayWithDuplicates.length; j++) {   
                hashmap.put(arrayWithDuplicates[j], j);   
            }   
            // use hashmap.keySet() for printing all keys of hashmap using it's keySet() method   
            System.out.println(hashmap.keySet());   
        
        }   
    }
```

out pout >>>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPkPB.png)

Comment: The OP **clearly** stated "_For this assignment I am not permitted to use any of the built-in libraries_". That's why I downvoted this answer. Please, delete this answer as it is not useful in the context of this assignment.